# How to get a resultCode sent from a service on Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm testing a service. The idea is usual: an activity calls the service giving it a pending intent, the service sends an intent back to the activity along with extra data and resultCode as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent().putExtra(TheService.SOME_REPLY, reason);
    pi.send(service, TheService.SOME_RESULT, intent);
```

I can retrieve the extra with a call to `shadowService.peekNextStartedActivity()`, but what about the resultCode? How and where can I retrieve it from?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), TheService.class)
            .setAction(action)
            .putExtra(TheService.EXTRA_PI, pi);

    service.onHandleIntent(intent);

    ShadowService shadowService = Shadows.shadowOf(service);
    Intent intent2 = shadowService.peekNextStartedActivity();
    assertNotNull(error, intent.getExtras());
    Object reply = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(TheService.SOME_REPLY);
    assertNotNull(reply);
    assertTrue(reply instanceof SomeReply);
    // ... etc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Robolectric shadow system works like a charm.

I added a new shadow class:

```
@Implements(PendingIntent.class)
public class ShadowPendingIntent extends org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPendingIntent {
    private int code;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    @Implementation
    protected void send(Context context, int code, Intent intent, PendingIntent.OnFinished onFinished, Handler handler, String requiredPermission, Bundle options) throws PendingIntent.CanceledException {
        this.code = code;
        super.send(context, this.code, intent, onFinished, handler, requiredPermission, options);
    }
}
```

Then used it in a test with the annotation:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(shadows = {ShadowPendingIntent.class})
public class TestXxx {
```

And finally check it in a test:

```
    ShadowPendingIntent spi = (ShadowPendingIntent) Shadows.shadowOf(pi);
    assertEquals(TheService.SOME_REPLY, spi.getCode());
```

Voilà.